# Prevent div re-sizing on filter in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs

This fiddle displays a list of div elements which allows filtering of these div's :

http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/18094/

If type "tester1" into filter items text box can see that this div is resized to max amount of horizontal space available. Can this be prevented so that div maintains its original size as filtering occurs ?

fiddle code :

```
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">

      <label>Filter Items: <input size=10 ng-model="icon"></label>

    <table class="table table-bordered" cellspacing="1">
      <tr ng-repeat="det in dets">
        <td class="col-md-3" ng-repeat="d in det | filter:icon">
          <div class="header"><a href="{{ d.title }}" target="_blank">{{d.title}}</div>

          <div class="title truncated-anchors"><a title="d.title" href='test");'>{{d.title}}</a>
          </div>

          <div class="date">test</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
/* Latest compiled and minified CSS included as External Resource*/

@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css');
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');
 .table-bordered {
  border: none;
}
.filter {
  /* margin-left:auto;
     margin-right:auto;
     */
  background-color: white;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 200px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
.center {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 1000px;
}
table {
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 20px;
}
td {
  /* padding: 5px 10px 5px 5px;
     */
  background-color: #F0F8FF;
}
.header {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  color: black;
}
.title {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.link {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.date {
  padding-top: 10px;
  font-style: italic;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.truncated-anchors {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

function MainCtrl($scope) {

  var iconDets = new Array();
  var icon1 = new Object();
  icon1.title = "tester1";
  var icon2 = new Object();
  icon2.title = "tester2";
  var icon3 = new Object();
  icon3.title = "tester3";
  var icon4 = new Object();
  icon4.title = "tester4";
  var icon5 = new Object();
  icon5.title = "tester5";
  var icon6 = new Object();
  icon6.title = "tester6 here";
  var icon7 = new Object();
  icon7.title = "tester6 here";


  iconDets.push(icon1);
  iconDets.push(icon2);
  iconDets.push(icon3);
  iconDets.push(icon4);
  iconDets.push(icon5);
  iconDets.push(icon6);
  iconDets.push(icon7);


  var i, j, temparray = [], chunk = 3;
  for (i = 0, j = iconDets.length; i < j; i += chunk) {
    temparray.push(iconDets.slice(i, i + chunk));
  }

  $scope.dets = temparray;

  var jsonString = JSON.stringify(iconDets);

};
```

Comment: Do you want to display the results in a table? Or can we change the markup? The reason I ask is because the filter causes the table to have only one column and thus it occupies the entire width of the screen

Comment: can't use float on a `<td>` and since table is full width when there is only one cell it will be full width. Problem stems from using `<table>`

Comment: @callmekatootie markup can be changed, thanks